# within python is there a way to correctly handle SSL certs with selenium rather than just ignoring the cert?

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, ssl-certificate

So I get an error when running a python webscraping script that I'm writing with selenium. since this is an net error code 202, what I'm learning is that this error code isn't stopping anything, but telling me that my ssl cert handling failed? when I look at the browser though, it does have a secure connection - so that's my first question - what exactly is failing? my code is performing its task correctly so I dont get what's wrong. (and why does it populate 4x when I'm only entering the browser once?)

my second question is how do I correctly handle the ssl cert to avoid the error code? I've read that I can just put in some code to ignore the cert error code, but since I'm learning python I think that's not the proper way I should go about it. what's your thoughts? (in any case I still need to learn how to circumnavigate the error because the way I've written it below is still giving me the same error)

error code:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55286/devtools/browser/0e343010-9339-4ad3-b5af-d9669f9d4ee9
[2380:10744:0409/192711.256:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
[2380:10744:0409/192711.296:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
[2380:10744:0409/192711.301:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
[2380:10744:0409/192711.459:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
[2380:10744:0409/192711.460:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(941)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
```

python script:

```
#this program will hopefully one day scrape info from walmart's website. this is a learning learning tool to learn pythonuses chrome driver version 80 saved to C:\drivers
chrome_path = r"C:\drivers\chromedriver_v80.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

#add chrome options to avoid SSL errors
woptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
woptions.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
woptions.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list")
woptions.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
woptions.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")
woptions.add_argument("--allow-insecure-localhost")
woptions.add_argument("--ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests")

#navigate to fruits and veggies page within groocery.walmart.com.
driver.get("https://grocery.walmart.com/")#browse/Fresh-Fruit?=&Vegetables_CP_Cat_Anchor_Fresh_Fruit=&aisle=1255027787131_1255027788181&page=1&povid=1255027787131%20%7C%20contentZone3%20%7C%202019-05-29%20%7C%201%20%7C%20Fruits&")
```